# Adding side button image to buttons

Tags: css, image

How do you add a side image to a button with css. I was doing some clean up on our site and converted a couple pages from table format to css using divs. Now the buttons do not have rounded sides like before, but we still have the side images. can someone show me how to just add those images back via divs or css after and before or something along those lines. here is what the div looks like and the css for the button.

```
<div>
    <!-- Edit Repair Button -->
    <cc1:TemplateButton ID="btnRepair" CssClass="costBenefitButton" runat="server" OnClientClickObjectPaths="0, RecordID; 1, CurrentUser"
        OnClientClickFormatString="ProblemRepair_problemID = '{0}'; User='{1}'; ModalDivEngine_ShowDiv('ProblemRepairDiv');"
        TextFormatString="<%$ Resources:CostBenefitDetails, CostBenefitDetails_btnRepair %>" />
    <%=TemplateManager.LOOP_TAG_END %>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.costBenefitButton
{
    background-image: url(../../Images/SubmitButtonBack.png);
    color: White;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 160px;
    height: 22px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Please no jquery or prototype plugins. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 background: #color url(../../Images/SubmitButtonBack.png) no-repeat left top;
```

This will put your image into top left corner of the button. Now, you might need to move the icon a little to have it perfectly placed, so instead of `left top` you might need to use pixel values (e.g. `2px 3px`), which is then position against the top left pixel of the button.

Comment: not sure i follow. I have the two side images, I want to be able to add them to each side of the button. If you are explaining that can you explain more and post more code. Thanks!